# Centering an objekt in php template. How?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, templates

I have a little problem with aligning a logo with some text in wordpress.

The more transparent logo is where I want my logo to be. It is in my header.php in my wordpress theme "Creator World".

I Really dont know what to do I have tried to research and I couldn't find anything. Hope you can help me  

[The more transparent logo and the arrow is sat in, in an design app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bziXA.jpg)

Here is my php code for my header.php in wordpress

```
 <?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div class="container">
 *
 * @package Creator World
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="pagewrap">
<div class="headertop">
 <div class="container">
      <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'header-info' ) ) : ?>
      <?php endif; // end header widget area ?>
 </div><!-- .container -->  
</div><!-- .headertop -->  


<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <?php creator_world_the_custom_logo(); ?>
      <h1><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
        </a></h1>
      <p>
        <?php bloginfo('description'); ?>
      </p>
    </div><!-- logo -->
    <div class="toggle"> <a class="toggleMenu" href="#">
      <?php _e('Menu','creator-world'); ?>
      </a> </div> <!-- toggle -->
    <div class="sitenav">
      <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary')); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- site-nav -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div><!-- container -->
</div><!--.header -->

<?php if ( is_front_page() && !is_home() ) { ?>
    <?php $hideslide = get_theme_mod('disabled_slides', '1'); ?>
        <?php if($hideslide == ''){ ?>               
                <?php for($sld=7; $sld<10; $sld++) { ?>
                    <?php if( get_theme_mod('page-setting'.$sld)) { ?>
                    <?php $slidequery = new WP_query('page_id='.get_theme_mod('page-setting'.$sld,true)); ?>
                    <?php while( $slidequery->have_posts() ) : $slidequery->the_post();
                            $image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
                            $img_arr[] = $image;
                            $id_arr[] = $post->ID;
                        endwhile;
                    }
                }
                ?>
<?php if(!empty($id_arr)){ ?>
        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <?php 
            $i=1;
            foreach($img_arr as $url){ ?>
            <?php if(!empty($url)){ ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="#slidecaption<?php echo $i; ?>" />
            <?php }else{ ?>
            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ) ; ?>/images/slides/slider-default.jpg" title="#slidecaption<?php echo $i; ?>" />
            <?php } ?>
            <?php $i++; }  ?>
        </div>   
<?php 
    $i=1;
        foreach($id_arr as $id){ 
        $title = get_the_title( $id ); 
        $post = get_post($id); 
        $content = esc_html( wp_trim_words( $post->post_content, 20, '' ) );
?>                 
<div id="slidecaption<?php echo $i; ?>" class="nivo-html-caption">
    <div class="slide_info">
        <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $content; ?></p>        
    </div>
</div>      
    <?php $i++; } ?>       
 <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<div class="clear"></div>        
<?php } ?>
<?php } } ?>


<?php if ( is_front_page() && ! is_home() ) { ?>
 <?php $hidewelcome = get_theme_mod('disabled_welcome', '1'); ?>
        <?php if($hidewelcome == ''){ ?>  
<section id="welcomesection">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="welcomebx">
      <?php if( get_theme_mod('page-setting1')) { ?>
      <?php $queryvar = new WP_query('page_id='.get_theme_mod('page-setting1' ,true)); ?>
      <?php while( $queryvar->have_posts() ) : $queryvar->the_post();?>     
     <h2 class="headingtitle">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
      </h2>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>                            
       <?php } ?>
    </div> <!-- welcomewrap-->
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div> <!-- container -->
</section>
<?php } ?> 


 <?php $hidepgbxes = get_theme_mod('disabled_pageboxes', '1'); ?>
        <?php if($hidepgbxes == ''){ ?>  
<section id="wrapsecond">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="services-wrap">
      <?php for($p=1; $p<5; $p++) { ?>
      <?php if( get_theme_mod('page-column'.$p,false)) { ?>
      <?php $querymy = new WP_query('page_id='.get_theme_mod('page-column'.$p,true)); ?>
      <?php while( $querymy->have_posts() ) : $querymy->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="fourbox <?php if($p % 4 == 0) { echo "last_column"; } ?>">           
            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                  <div class="thumbbx"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a> </div>
            <?php } ?>
           <div class="pagecontent">          
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3> 
                <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 20, '...' );  ?></p>           
                <a class="pagemore" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                 <?php _e('Read More','creator-world'); ?>
                </a>
           </div>
        </div>
       <?php endwhile;
             wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php } } ?>      
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>   <!-- services-wrap-->
  </div> <!-- container -->
</section>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't center a logo through php. The right way will be css. Search by css and you will find many ways to achieve this. Or post the link of your site so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code to the following, adding a new `div` with class `brand-name` and leaving only the logo in the one with `logo` class.

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="brand-name">
        <h1><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
         </a></h1>
         <p>
            <?php bloginfo('description'); ?>
         </p>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
        <?php creator_world_the_custom_logo(); ?>
    </div><!-- logo -->
    <div class="toggle"> <a class="toggleMenu" href="#">
      <?php _e('Menu','creator-world'); ?>
      </a> </div> <!-- toggle -->
    <div class="sitenav">
      <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary')); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- site-nav -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div><!-- container -->
</div><!--.header -->
```

Then, add the following lines in CSS:

```
.brand-name, .logo {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I'ts in the opposite side there were I want it. and the text is right on the border to the background. can I do something to it? thanks
http://sogpservice.dk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Skærmbillede-2016-10-31-kl.-18.31.01.png

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping the logo and title to the individual `div` elements

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="brand-title pull-left">
      <h1><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
        </a></h1>
      <p>
        <?php bloginfo('description'); ?>
      </p>
    </div><!-- Brand Title -->
    <div class="brand-logo pull-left">
      <?php creator_world_the_custom_logo(); ?>
    </div><!-- Brand logo -->
    <div class="toggle"> <a class="toggleMenu" href="#">
      <?php _e('Menu','creator-world'); ?>
      </a> </div> <!-- toggle -->
    <div class="sitenav">
      <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary')); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- site-nav -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div><!-- container -->
</div><!--.header -->
```

and then add the following code to your CSS file (usually this is **style.css**)

```
.pull-left {
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: it sort of worked but now its just in top of the text, it have to be in the middle and have a little space between the border to the background 

Comment: Heres an image  
http://sogpservice.dk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Skærmbillede-2016-10-31-kl.-18.23.53.png